# Flash when changing the screen with fading out effect

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to achieve a simple fadeIn and fadeOut effect when transitioning between screens. I have set a stage but when designing my app I did not use any actors. Therefore, I have put it a black screen as an actor and then I set the alpha to 0 on show(). When fading out what I do is I fade in the black image using

```
stage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeIn(1), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                game.setScreen(new gameScreen(game));
```

This works, however there is a small problem, right at the end of the fade there is a small flash for a millisecond which shows the previous screen before it switches so the transition is not smooth, the black image is removed before switching screens. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that **stage.clear()** and **stage.dispose()** is being called before rest of your app is being rendered last time.

The solution is to override **dispose()** Screen method and manually set some flag **shouldBeRendered** to false and then dispose your stage.

```
    boolean shouldBeRendered = true;

    ...

    public void render(float delta)
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if(shouldBeRendered)
        {
            //here you render all
        }

        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        shouldBeRendered = false;

        stage.clear();
        stage.dispose();
    }
```

You can add some **System.out.println()** to both render and dispose methods to see the flow of **Screen** circle of life